# how to Clipboard.GetText() in my Localhost:5001 Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, wcf, blazor

Good morning,
I have a windows forms appliation which contains a button, I want from button to copy an ID and paste it in my  Localhost:5001 Application's tag ( a simple input tag), i succeed to make the copy function but when it comes to paste , i can't figure out how to Clipboard.GetText() in my Localhost:5001 Application ?

```
 private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
           ???? = Clipboard.GetText();
        }
```

Any help please !

Comment: This will not work. Just send it to your webservice via http or use any other means of inter-process communication

Comment: the problem is that when i use webservice i need to refresh the page, but in my case all i need to a real time communication, the ID will how in my localhost application without refreshing the webpage

Answer (score 0):

A web app is hosted in a browser sandbox, so it cannot access any desktop resources at its will but under the control of the web browser.

For JavaScript based web apps you can use [browser's Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard), while for .NET Blazor there is a [NuGet package](https://github.com/Basaingeal/Razor.Clipboard).